# How to get company information using Linkedin API

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to get company information, using linkedin company search api.
here, I am using

```
$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/companies::(universal-name=example-companyname)');
$company = fetch('GET', '/v1/companies/'.$user->values[0]->id.':(id,name,ticker,description,universal-name,email-domains,company-type,website-url,industries,status,logo-url,square-logo-url,blog-rss-url,twitter-id,employee-count-range,specialties,locations,stock-exchange,founded-year,end-year,num-followers)');
```

Here, I am using universal name to fetch the company information. This is absolutely working fine. Now, I need to get the same company information using website url.

I mean, I need to pass the website url as a parameter and need to fetch the company information.

Comment: Checkout this 

   [From stackoverflow ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781581/linkedin-api-for-company-directory/4696576#4696576

Comment: How do you think that is even possible?!