# Is it possible to search for a person or company in LinkedIn's API?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am trying to search for a company/person through LinkedIn's current API by using the directions provided on this post

[LinkedIn API for Company Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781581/linkedin-api-for-company-directory)

They use the following URL:

```
http://www.linkedin.com/ta/federator?query=citr&types=company,group,sitefeature
```

However, it seems like the api link has been deprecated. Can someone who works extensively with LinkedIn's API let me know if there is a way to perform a search and get a JSON of the search results? I want to be able to look up a company and get it's company ID so that I can pull information from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn has limited its API access some time ago. See the [details](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition). Inorder to do a person search you should get vetted [API access](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api) from linkedin